# How to use a proxy server with 'httr2'?

Tags: r, curl, libcurl, httr, httr2

I am currently writing an R script that scrapes yahoo finance and ETFDB.com, I need to scrape the websites in parallel and use a proxy server to split up the HTTP GET IP's so that I don't get ban from those upstream servers.

There is an easy implementation of `httr::use_proxy`, although this feature/function is missing in httr2.

Does anybody know a work around to this without setting global `curl` proxy settings to the proxy server?

Comment: Check out [this helpful issue thread](https://github.com/r-lib/httr2/issues/77) on the httr2 github page. My guess is this is more or less what you're looking for?